# suspend not working: Dell i15-5505, Ryzen 7

Tags: suspend, dell, inspiron, mint, amd-ryzen

I have the classic Linux laptop suspend problem.  I just bought a new, shiny laptop.  I'm running Mint 20.1 with Mate on a Dell i15-5505 with Ryzen 7 4700, 16GB RAM, 256GB+1TB SSDs.  The kernel version is 5.4.0-65-generic.

The behavior I see is:

- When I close the lid, the display goes off (not just dim).  However, when I raise the lid, I do not get a login screen, but rather the display as it was when I closed the lid, and it's clear the machine did not suspend.
- If I suspend via the Mint menu, or if I use "systemctl suspend", the machine appears to suspend, but it isn't fully powered down and continues to draw about 4W, and the bottom of the machine is warm.  When I hit the Shift key, the screen lights, and I get a login prompt.

I'll mention the dreaded "It works with Windows 10."

A comment on this page:
https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/hardware/processors-memory/1178768-initial-amd-ryzen-7-4700u-linux-performance-is-very-good/page8
seems to suggest that a newer kernel, low-latency version. solves the problems, but it doesn't for my machine.  I tried linux-kernel-5.8.0-43-lowlatency, but, sadly, that didn't help me.  I also tried 5.10.0-1013.14, also unsuccessfully.

I really hope I can find a resolution.  I think this is a gorgeous laptop, sleek, lightweight, beautiful display, fast.  But not being able to suspend is a real deal-killer, even though the low pseudo-suspend current draw does allow me to use the machine on battery for a decent length of time.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

SUCCESS.

I found a posting online that provided the outline of a solution.  The short version is that the Dell's ACPI configuration had to be modified. Apparently Windows uses something called "connected standby" in place of the familiar "sleep to RAM" suspend, and Dell's ACPI did not have the S3 deep sleep mode available.  The solution entailed adding it back in.

The outline of the solution is here: https://dev.to/epassaro/fix-suspend-issues-on-dell-7405-2-in-1-3l1b.

Here are some specific changes to the procedure outlined in the above.

Step 0: Use a recent Linux Kernel

I'm running Mint 20.1, which uses a 5.4 kernel.  According to the post, a 5.8 kernel or later is required.  The 5.8.0 kernel did not work for me, but the 5.10.0-1013-oem kernel did.

Step 2: Recompile DSDT and examine errors

The `iasl_errors.txt` file has lots of stuff but only three errors, which, as the post says, you have to look for with a text editor.  In my ACPI, the error lines were 3981, 4018, 4046.

I followed the rest of the procedure, and my laptop sleeps!  And wakes up!